# "Unfortunately app has stopped" error while sending httppost request to Bluemix deployed Node.js app

Tags: android, node.js, api, rest, ibm-cloud

I am creating an Android app, but while sending the parameters using `httppost` method to Bluemix deployed Node.js server, I am getting "Unfortunately app has stopped" error.
Can anyone help me in this issue?

And I have query, am not able to receive response from Node.js the ticket link:  [Am not able to send my request parameters to bluemix deployed node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799038/am-not-able-to-send-my-request-parameters-to-bluemix-deployed-node-js?noredirect=1#comment47776784_29799038)

Jave code as given below:

```
      package com.example.rest;

       import java.io.IOException;
       import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
       import java.util.ArrayList;
       import java.util.List;
      import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
      import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
      import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
      import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
     import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
      import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
      import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
      import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
     import android.app.Dialog;
     import android.content.SharedPreferences;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.util.Log;
      import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.MenuItem;
      import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Adapter;
     import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


String url = "http://mobilefeedbackform.mybluemix.net/";
List<NameValuePair> params;
SharedPreferences pref;
Dialog reset;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button breg1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonreg);

    breg1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        public void onClick(View v) {

            final EditText Name =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextreg5);
            final EditText Email =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextreg);
            final EditText Passwd =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextreg2);

            if(Name.getText().toString().length()==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Please enter Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                return;
            }

            else if(Email.getText().toString().length()==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Please enter EmailId", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                return;
            }

            else if(Passwd.getText().toString().length()==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Please enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                String nametxt = Name.getText().toString();
                String emailtxt = Email.getText().toString();
                String passwdtxt = Passwd.getText().toString();

             // Creating HTTP client
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // Creating HTTP Post
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://mobilefeedbackform.mybluemix.net");

                // Building post parameters
                // key and value pair
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nametxt));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", nametxt));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwdtxt));

                // Url Encoding the POST parameters
                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // writing error to Log
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Making HTTP Request
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    // writing response to log
                    Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // writing exception to log
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // writing exception to log
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }




            }
            }



        });

}
```

}

and my error logs are given below:

```
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 18:26:13.799:     E/AndroidRuntime(528):android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
 04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
 04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
 04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):    at com.example.rest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:106)
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
   04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
   04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
  04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
   04-24 18:26:13.799: E/AndroidRuntime(528):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: **post your stacktrace in logcat**

Comment: I am guessing your app has stopped! based on the error message. Please provide the full error message and stack. Plus have you checked that your server node app is still running? Look at `cf events` to see what state changes your app is going through.

Comment: Am testing in device itself because i have problem with my emulator........

Comment: Am error logs are given above

Comment: Can you post some more info?  Its kind of hard to understand where you are having your issue.

Comment: I posted log cat errors, Can you tell me what you need more?

Answer (score 3):

The error is because you are attempting a network call on the main thread in Android and the [strictmode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) policy is being activated to block it. You can see this in the stacktrace at this line `android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork`.

You should look at executing network calls on a separate thread. Strictmode is there to help give a better experience to the end user.

Comment: Have a look at using Asynctask to offload the network call to another thread and then update your UI when the task completes. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html